# Откуда яндекс тянет библиотеки js

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите пожалуйста от куда Яндекса тянет библиотеки.
у меня на странице юзаются вот такие

```
<script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="language.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="object_manager_filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="placemark_hint_layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

локально собирается. в тимсити на стенде пытаюсь запустить и вот такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где вы подключаете API? [Вот документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/load-docpage/?from=SO)

Comment: <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.17/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
только такая строчка есть. получается чтобы тестировать версию нужно сразу приобретать ключ Яндекса?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что эти файлы вы не должны подключать самостоятельно. Подключать надо API карт

Comment: да вроде так и есть спасибо.

Comment: использование API бесплатно для большинства задач, нужно просто получить ключ